# Using XMPP, can I send a message without subscription?

Tags: xmpp, xmpp4r

I am currently writing a XMPP bot using `xmpp4r` (Ruby) but when it sends a message to a user using the same XMPP server, it does not deliver to the user. My condition is:

1. The bot user is registered at XMPP server x.
2. The human user who will get the message is also registered at same XMPP server x.
3. Both users are connected to that server and are online.
4. **There is no subscription or invite between users.**
5. At this time, the bot user needs to send a message to the human user.

Is this possible, or what can I do to send message from bot?

Comment: It is possible that the server was programmed to not deliver any messages between two users that don't have any subscriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible (and intended behavior) to deliver messages to XMPP entities where the sending entity has a subscription state of 'none'.

I suggest you have a look at the server logs or listen for error messages to determine why the message isn't delivered.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I used jappix.com for this test and I donot have my own server, and there is no error message from server. how can I find the problem?

Comment: I don't know deeply but the problem is solved. I had test again with another client software and it works fine. maybe it is client app's behavior. thanks.